SpringBoot Oauth2 Client Error In Creating Security Filter Chain
I have Spring Boot Gateway which is also acting as a Oauth2 Client here I am trying to also add SpringSecurityFilter chain in the Gateway by,
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
.anyRequest().authenticated()
)
.oauth2Client(Customizer.withDefaults())
.oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());
return http.build();
}

But doing so I am getting the error
The bean 'springSecurityFilterChain', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/reactive/ReactiveOAuth2ClientConfigurations$ReactiveOAuth2ClientConfiguration$SecurityWebFilterChainConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.

I am not able to understand why this is happening since I have added SecurityFilterChain in Oauth2 Resource server and Oauth 2 Authorization servers and no problem has occured in them I am new in this any help is appreciated
If any other information is required please let me know
Below are the dependencies added in the project
<properties>  
<java.version>21</java.version>  
<spring-cloud.version>2023.0.1</spring-cloud.version>  
</properties>  
<dependencies>  
<dependency>  
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>  
</dependency>  
<dependency>  
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>  
<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>  
<version>4.1.1</version>  
</dependency>  
<dependency>  
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>  
<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>  
</dependency>  
<dependency>  
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>  
<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer</artifactId>  
</dependency>  
<dependency>  
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>  
<version>3.2.2</version>  
</dependency>  
<dependency>  
<groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>  
<artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>  
<version>6.0.0</version>  
<scope>provided</scope>  
</dependency>  
<dependency>  
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>  
<scope>test</scope>  
</dependency>  
</dependencies>  
<dependencyManagement>  
<dependencies>  
<dependency>  
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>  
<artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>  
<version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>  
<type>pom</type>  
<scope>import</scope>  
</dependency>  
</dependencies>  
</dependencyManagement>  

Since the spring-security-filter chain works in almost every other micorservice normally it is behaving different in Oauth2 Client I am not able to understand why this is happening

There are a few reasons this might be happening but one is a fact. There is already an existing bean for SecurityFilterChain in the application you are changing hence the error, it is either already configured/defined in a class or through existing dependencies. Check this article https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-security-autoconfiguration It might help you understand based on what you have in your app

@JorgeCampos I have tried above resource but it does not work can the possible reason for the problem be that since I am also using spring-starter-gateway hence SpringSecurity is not working ? ServerHttpSecurity is working no error on that but HttpSecurity is not working

I can't say for sure. Maybe try setting your application logs to debug, then look in the logs what is initiating the SecurityFilterChain (besides your own) then you will likely be able to figure out what is causing the problem.
